# cannot implicitly cast A[T] to AT, where A[T] extends AT

Tags: java, scala, generics

The problem is related to integration between Java and Scala. I have simplified it a little bit to make things clearer.

I have two classes written in Java:

```
class A<T>{}

class AT extends A<Boolean> {}
```

In Java I have a method that uses the classes in the following way:

```
public  A<Boolean> a(){
    return new AT();
}
```

I would like to do the same thing in scala. But the code below doesn't compile.

```
def a(): A[Boolean] = {
    return new AT();
}
```

The message says: "type mismatch; found : org.rarry.sample.AT required: org.rarry.sample.A[Boolean]"

Can anybody explain why it is so, and how to go about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand the reason your code doesn't compile, first note that Java uses `java.lang.Boolean` for the boxed boolean type, and Scala uses `scala.Boolean`. Most of the time, when you want to use one of them, and a method returns the other one (or a method argument requires the other one), an implicit conversion will be performed, and the correct type will be used.

The method `a` that you wrote in Scala really returns `A[java.lang.Boolean]`. Because there's no implicit conversion between `A[java.lang.Boolean]` and `A[scala.Boolean]`, it will not automatically return `A[scala.Boolean]` in this case.

To verify that this is the case, we can see that this method compiles without issues:

```
def a: A[java.lang.Boolean] = new AT()
```

To reiterate the point, because we don't have the implicit conversion, this will also not work (you'll see how that can be fixed below):

```
val instanceOfA: A[Boolean] = a
def a = new AT()
// Error: AT doesn't conform to A[Boolean]
```

To fix it, you could implicitly convert to the needed type by casting it:

```
implicit def toScalaABoolean(a: A[java.lang.Boolean]): A[Boolean] =
        a.asInstanceOf[A[Boolean]]
```

With that done, you don't even have to declare the return type of `a` method anymore:

```
implicit def toDifferentBoolean(a: A[java.lang.Boolean]): A[Boolean] = 
     a.asInstanceOf[A[Boolean]]
val instanceOfA: A[Boolean] = a
def a = new AT()
```